# How do I print a float only when the input is a float, or print an integer only when the input is an integer?

Tags: python, type-conversion, integer

I am a very new programmer. I have created this calculator in python, and I wanted to polish it up a bit. Whenever I make a calculation, the answer is always printed as a float, even when both inputs were just integers. (for example: 5 + 5 = 10.0) I know this is because I convert the inputs to floats immediately, but I am entirely lost on how I can make the answer appear as a float only when one of the inputs contains a decimal. Thank you for any help in advance.

Here is my code (I know it is a bit messy, my bad, I am quite new):

while True:
try:
calculating = input('would you like to make a calculation? (y/n) ')

```
    if calculating in ('y', 'yes'):
        try:
            numberOne = float(input('Enter your first number. '))
            operation = input('Enter your operator. ')
            if operation not in ('+', '-', '*', 'x', '/'):
                print('That is not an operator.')
                continue
            numberTwo = float(input('Enter your second number. '))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            continue

        if operation == '+':
            print(float(numberOne) + float(numberTwo))
        if operation == '-':
            print(float(numberOne) - float(numberTwo))
        if operation in ('*', 'x'):
            print(float(numberOne) * float(numberTwo))
        try:
            if operation == '/':
                print(float(numberOne) / float(numberTwo))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Error: Division by 0')
            continue

    elif calculating in ('n', 'no'):
        print('Okay')
        break

    if calculating not in ('y', 'n', 'yes', 'no'):
        print('It is one or the other')
        continue

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I tried having two seperate blocks where the inputs are actually calculated, each with an
"if numberOne == float/int or numberTwo == float/int" statement before. I realized this wasn't working because I was saving each input as a float as soon as it was entered because of the float() function around the input(). However, if I were to remove that it would be stored as a string and then I wouldn't know how to convert it to either a float or an integer based on whether or not it contained a decimal. I am sure there is a simple fix to this problem, but I am just not seeing it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if a decimal point is present in the string input, *before* converting to int/float.

```
number = input("Enter a number ")
if "." in number:
    number = float(number)
else:
    number = int(number)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment. It seems like it should work, but I might be doing something wrong. I now get this error: "argument of type 'float' is not iterable" when I enter my first number, either float or integer.

Comment: @SayJokes It sounds like you still have `float(input(...))` instead of just `input()`.

Comment: Dude thank you so much. I can't believe I forgot about 'if "." in'.

Answer (score 0):

Here, some changes are,

while True:
try:
calculating = input('would you like to make a calculation? (y/n) ')
if calculating in ('y', 'yes'):
try:
numberOne = float(input('Enter your first number. '))
operation = input('Enter your operator. ')
if operation not in ('+', '-', '*', 'x', '/'):
print('That is not an operator.')
continue
numberTwo = float(input('Enter your second number. '))
except ValueError as e:
print(e)
continue

```
        if operation == '+':
            res=numberOne+numberTwo
        if operation == '-':
            res=numberOne+numberTwo
        if operation in ('*', 'x'):
            res=numberOne+numberTwo
        try:
            if operation == '/':
                res=numberOne/numberTwo
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print('Error: Division by 0')
            continue
        if float.is_integer(res):
            print(int(res))
        else:
            print(res)

   elif calculating in ('n', 'no'):
        print('Okay')
        break

   if calculating not in ('y', 'n', 'yes', 'no'):
        print('It is one or the other')
        continue

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the method `.is_integer` in the result value and if it returns true you print the value with an integer cast eg.

```
numberOne = float(input("Insert number one: "))
numberTwo = float(input("Insert number two: "))

result = numberOne + numberTwo

if float.is_integer(result):
    print(int(result))
else:
    print(result)
```

Comment: `int(numberOne)` This code is useless by itself.  You'd have to assign the result back to the variable `numberOne = int(numberOne)`

Comment: You are correct!, I'll edit the post, thank you

Comment: this will fail miserably if the float value can't be represented exactly in float. For example values that are too large like 10**5000 can't be stored in a float but can be stored in int. Or most of the values larger than 2^53 won't be exactly representable in float (because python uses IEEE754 binary64) like 9007199254740993 or 9007199254740992.6, they'll be reported as int. Same to values that are longer that float's precision such as 1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000003174

Comment: another issue is that if users enter for example 23e5 or 6.0, they're completely valid float but will be reported as integer